# Is there any way to replicate redis across data centers?

Tags: redis, replication

I've tired dynomite and dynomite-manager but it has many dependencies(aws integration, works on tomcat, using cassandra for token storage). Is there any way to do replication across data centers in redis.

Comment: Have you tried using a `redis cluster`?

Comment: I'm expecting similar to master(dc1)-master(dc2) replication

Comment: Yup, that is `redis clustering`. You would create your masters in one Datacenter and have replication spread out to other datacenters. If you want a script that does it for you let me know and I can post it in the answers. The problem with replicating over large networks would be the lag, and increased network traffic.

Comment: if i'm going to use as you said dc1 master and dc2 slave, then there is a lag while fetching data from dc2. What i'm expecting is, dc2 is only for replication.

Comment: Your comment didnt have a question, just a statement. Is there some question you want to ask?